# Load dynamic Image in tableHeaderView

Tags: iphone

I want to add a dynamic image in the UITableView's tableHeaderView part.

For that i am writing following code :

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 
                                                                           0.0f, 
                                                                           320.0f, 
                                                                           44.0f)];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = myImageView;
[myImageView release];
```

With this code i am getting image in my screen, but with stretched view.

Now i want to set that image at the particular corner of HeaderView of table.

Anyone have any solution then please help me..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your UIImageView to a regular container UIView and place it inside that.

Comment: Yep. Exactly what I would've said.